# Manuel injected Spring Bean Does not Invoke PostConstructor

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot Version : 2.7.15

After Upgrading from Java 8 to Java 17
I added this into my pom.xml in order using @PostConstructor

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.annotation-api.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I have many different micro services and I manage my spring beans with spring annotations like (@Service etc..)

I also  have another CommonManager library which is common for all micro services and it is isn't depend on spring. You can see how it looks like below

```java
public class ExampleEnvironmentClass {
    

    private Class<? extends ADao> aDaoClass = ADaoImpl.class;
    private Class<? extends AManager> aManagerClass = AManagerImpl.class;

    private Class<? extends BDao> bDaoClass = BDaoImpl.class;
    private Class<? extends BManager> bManagerClass = BManagerImpl.class;

}

public class ExampleManagerImpl implements ExampleManager {

    public ExampleManagerImpl (ExampleEnvironmentClass env) {
        this(env, null);
    }

        //Another Constuctor for direct call 
    public ExampleManagerImpl (ExampleEnvironmentClass env, Dao dao) {
        env.validate();
        //...
        //...
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize () {
        //
    }

}
```

While I'm using CommonManager library in my microservices i'm defining it with @Bean annotation.

```java
@SpringBootApplication (exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableScheduling
@Import ({ DbConfiguration.class//
        , CacheClientConfiguration.class//
        , WebMvcConfiguration.class//
})

public class MySpringMicroService {

        @Bean
    public ExampleManager exampleManager () {

        ExampleEnvironmentClass env = new ExampleEnvironmentClass();

        env.aDaoClass(CustomADaoImpl.class);
        env.aManagerClass(CustomAManagerImpl.class);

        //env.bDaoClass(CustomBDaoImpl.class);
        env.bManagerClass(CustomAManagerImpl.class);

        
        return new ExampleManagerImpl(env);
    }

}
```

For example `env.bDaoClass(CustomBDaoImpl.class);` this is commented. So that means for this micro service it will continue to using BDaoImpl.class as defined in the CommonManager library.

With this way, my micro services can have different framework. A micro service can run on Micronaut and B services can run on Spring.

Until upgrading Java 17. It was working well with Spring Boot 2.7.15 as I expected.
I'm planning to switch Spring Boot 3.0  so I switch Java 17 from Java 8.

**But now @PostConstructor in the ExampleManagerImpl isn't invoked. **

I tried to adding `@ComponentScans` but it didn't work.

```java
@ComponentScans({
        @ComponentScan("CommonLibraryPackage"),
        @ComponentScan("MyServicesOwnComponentPage") //It is actually unnecassary. Spring automatically find but i added for trying
})
```

Edit: As an workaround solution. Manual call solved my problem. But it would be good to use @PostConstruct

```
 
//return new ExampleManagerImpl(env); //instead of this
ExampleManagerImpl obj = new ExampleManagerImpl(env);
obj.initialize();
return obj;
```

Last Edit and Solution:

Instead of using jakarta.annotation-api library. I used javax.annotation-api external library and it solved my problem.

```xml
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Instead of using jakarta.annotation-api library. I used javax.annotation-api external library and it solved my problem.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
```

Explanation : Until Spring Boot 2.7.x were using javax.* but after Spring Boot 3.x Spring Boot that makes use of Jakarta EE 9 APIs (jakarta.*) instead of EE 8 (javax.*)

That means, when I upgrade my spring from 2.7 to 3.0, I have to replace javax with jakarta.

Answer (score -1):

Javas `new` operator doesn't know about or use annotations, so as soon as you use that, you will have to call any initialization methods on your own.

But I see a bigger problem here: you create an object with `new` that seems to be unusable without calling the `initialize` method. Why don't you call `initialize` directly in the constructor? As the method is public, it could be overridden by a subclass and then it's code will probably not be executed, which could lead to an inconsistent state.

If you must keep it that way, you could create a bean for the `ExampleEnvironmentClass`, probably multiple ones, with `@Qualifier` annotations, to resemble various environments.
And remove the bean for `ExampleManager`.

If `ExampleManagerImpl` is the only class that implements `ExampleManager`, Spring will take care of instanciating it and then also should execute the `@PostConstruct` annotated method.